# Return multiple regex match groups from an nmap returned results

Tags: bash, shell-script, sed, grep, regular-expression

I have an nmap script that run tests for open-relays on a list of IPs.
Initially I had to return only the hostname and the IP of a host if it was found that it has an open port from the specified ports in the command, but this seems to be not accurate because an open port doesn't mean the NSE tests are successful.
so, I want to return the hostname and IP + the NSE result in one row.

The command I used is:

```
nmap --script smtp-open-relay.nse --open -p 25,2525,587,465,2526 -iL ./short_servers_list.txt
```

The example output from this command is:

> *Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2017-08-08 07:25 PDT
>
> Nmap scan report for **foo01.bar.com (10.10.10.1)**
>
> Host is up (0.0020s latency).
>
> Not shown: 3 closed ports
>
> PORT     STATE SERVICE
>
> 25/tcp   open  smtp
>
> |_**smtp-open-relay: Server is an open relay (5/16 tests)**
>
> 2526/tcp open  unknown
>
> Nmap scan report for **foo02.bar.com (10.10.10.2)**
>
> Host is up (0.082s latency).
>
> Not shown: 4 closed ports
>
> PORT   STATE SERVICE
>
> 25/tcp open  smtp
>
> |_**smtp-open-relay: SMTP EHLO nmap.scanme.org: failed to receive
>   data: connection closed**
>
> Nmap done: 10 IP addresses (6 hosts up) scanned in 2.16 seconds*

I need to output the following:

> foo01.bar.com (10.10.10.1) smtp-open-relay: Server is an open relay (5/16 tests)
>
> foo02.bar.com (10.10.10.2) smtp-open-relay: SMTP EHLO nmap.scanme.org: failed to receive

how can I do that using common bash tools/commands (grep or sed etc.)?

Comment: `nmap` has `-oG` for "greppable" output or `-oX` for XML output, if you need something more easily processable by script

Answer (score 0):

With ***awk***:

```
nmap --script smtp-open-relay.nse --open -p 25,2525,587,465,2526 -iL ./short_servers_list.txt \
| awk '/^ *Nmap scan report/{ sub(/^ *Nmap scan report for */, "", $0); printf "%s ",$0 }
       /_smtp-open-relay/{ sub(/^ *\|_/, "", $0); print $0 }'
```

Comment: @DaveIce, welcome, have you tried to accept the answer?